# Unbounded and wait-free?

Tags: java, concurrency, nonblocking

This is the description of the documentation of [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html):

> An unbounded thread-safe queue based on linked nodes. This queue orders elements FIFO (first-in-first-out).
>   ...
>   This implementation employs an efficient "wait-free" algorithm

Is it possible to be *unbounded* **and** *wait-free*?
 I am pretty sure wait-freedom ensures a bound on any operation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I am pretty sure wait-freedom ensures a bound on any operation.

A bound on the *time* (or number of instructions, or whatever) taken by the operation.

In that JavaDoc, "Unbounded" probably refers to the *number of elements* the queue may contain.

For instance, the JavaDoc for LinkedBlockingDeque [writes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingDeque.html):

> An optionally-bounded blocking deque based on linked nodes.
>
> The optional capacity bound constructor argument serves as a way to prevent excessive expansion. The capacity, if unspecified, is equal to Integer.MAX_VALUE. Linked nodes are dynamically created upon each insertion unless this would bring the deque above capacity.

Answer (score 2):

Wait-freedom really just implies within some finite number of steps an operation will complete as [explained](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_algorithm)

> An algorithm is wait-free if every operation has a bound on the number
>   of steps the algorithm will take before the operation completes

This definition doesn't apply to the `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`. When polling (or putting) a queue, each thread has the likelihood of failing an infinite number of times. This fact alone tells us that the queue is not truly wait free. I believe the author isn't using the definition of wait-free from Herlihy in The Art of Multiprocessor Programming.

For more information, the CLQ uses a Michael & Scott alogrithm that is explained [here](http://www.research.ibm.com/people/m/michael/podc-1996.pdf)

Edit:  Just realised the link I gave for the M and S queue is also in the API.  Either should be fine.

Comment: in what way `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` is wait free if by definition it doesn't use a finite number of steps? In mentioned `poll` operation(and `offer` also) there is an infinite loop which on each iteration performs some CAS operations. It's basically a structure of lock-free algorithm

Comment: That's a fair point. The 4 years-ago-me shouldve wrote that it was lock-free queue and not wait free. I'll update the answer.

Comment: FYI, the Java 7 javadocs erroneously claim that the algorithm that ConcurrentLinkedQueue is based on is wait-free. This has been corrected in the Java 8 javadocs which correctly state that it is in fact non-blocking.